# How do i configure WSAT version in JBoss?

Tags: java, jboss, cxf, wsat

I am using a CXF client to implement a WSAT web service call. The following namespace is added on the outbound coordination context header:

wscoor="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-tx/wscoor/2006/06"

This namespace is used by WSAT 1.2. How can i configure either the client or JBoss to use WSAT 1.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the only way to do this is to bundle an older version of Apache CXF in jboss as shown below:

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/803623